# Linux missing sound configurations

Tags: sound

[image]

Hi guys, as you see on ss my linux is missing sound configurations. I need them because my sound sounds like someone was talking under water
im using **HDA Intel PCH at 0xc7500000 irq 38**

Comment: might help to indicate what ubuntu version you are using. [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: Software stack details are needed to fully understand the issue & fixes - ie. what OS & release you're using as already asked.  Options & commands aren't the same for all on-topic OSes.